# Bootstrap Carousel not displaying caption due to fixed height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with my Bootstrap Carousel. It Works, shows the images, sliding, but it wont show text if I set a fixed height to it. I've tried many solutions I could find online, but non of them worked in my case.

Here's my code:

```css
.carousel {
  max-height: 500px !important;
}

.carousel-inner {
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-caption {
  background-color: transparent;
  max-width: 550px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style=" width:100%; height: 500px !important;">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://www.dailydooh.com/wp-content/uploads/img/standard/300x250.gif" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>dgsdg</h5>
        <p>sdgsdgdsg</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://www.dailydooh.com/wp-content/uploads/img/standard/300x250.gif" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>dgsdg</h5>
        <p>sdgsdgdsg</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://www.dailydooh.com/wp-content/uploads/img/standard/300x250.gif" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>dgsdg</h5>
        <p>sdgsdgdsg</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add a plunker example.

Comment: Your code worked for me.  I changed the caption color to red, just in case. And I had to change the class from 'carousel-item' to 'item'.